# Инвентарь в браузерной игре

Tags: html, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно прочитать, как сделать вот так:

[image: картинка]

или подкиньте ответ =)

Comment: Простая html табличка, выпадающий список и инпут...

Вопрос неачем :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хедер:

```
<style type="text/css">
P#right {
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#left {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#right {
 text-align: right;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.inventar {
 background-color: skyblue;
}
table, td, tr {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Туда куда нужно вставить:

```
<div class="inventar">
<p id="right">Инвентарь</p>
<select>
<optgroup label="Все">
<option>йцу</option>
</optgroup> 
</select>
<div id="left">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
-
</td>
<td>
-
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
-
</td>
<td>
-
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="right">
<forum action="script">
<input name="whats">
<input type="submit" value="Выкинуть">
</form>
</div>
<a href="#">-Обновить-</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Я конечно не проверял на работоспособность, но должно быть всё отлично.

Comment: Блин=) я что не спрошу здесь, все равно придется делать самому , вот что я от вас просил : <table width="150" border="0"  height="150"  cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#2e4d3d">
<tr bgcolor="#47795F">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#47795F">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#47795F">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
все равно спасибо =)

Comment: Хах, а я подумал что нужен целый слой со всеми этими

Comment: =) нее=) спс за помощь =)

Comment: @Prikol ты бы еще написал - почему я должен за вас делать свою работу?!